# Changing sharepoint file modification time

Tags: sharepoint-online

how can I programmatically modify the file creation and modification time for Sharepoint online files?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't! Because the created and Modified date field are system fields.

Instead create a custom created date field then hide the original one

Answer (score 0):

We could use **Send An HTTP Request To SharePoint** action to update the Modified time and Created time with Microsoft Flow.

Simple test for your reference:

[image]

Result：

[image]

More information for your reference:

http://johnliu.net/blog/2019/2/flowninja-hack-78-modifying-modified-by-and-modified-time-with-microsoft-flow